# How to set breakpoint in a specific program when they are many loaded at the same address?

Tags: gdb, kernel, qemu, gdbserver

I am debugging a system which consist of a kernel and some user programs and I want to trace one of these user programs. The problem is they are all loaded at the same virtual address; so that when I set a breakpoint at an address; it gets hit when the execution passes by this address in any of my user programs.
I know that one way to solve it would be to load them in different address spaces, but I would like to avoid it if there is a better way...

I use qemu to emulate x86 architecture in order to run the system (Kernel + user code). 
In order to debug, I use an external gdb client which connects to gdbserver running on qemu.

Comment: How do you set your breakpoints ? What architecture are you using ? What system is it (linux-based ?) ? Default breakpoints with gdb should be code-dependent, and not address-dependent.

Comment: As presented, this has nothing to do with C.  The solution depends on things you have not provided.  What does the development system you are using provide?  What does its documentation say?

Comment: To set a breakpoint i do, break *address.

Comment: @ryyker You are right, it is not specific to c; I updated the post. C is the language I am programming in

Comment: You can attach [break conditions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Conditions.html#Conditions) to a breakpoint, and check the values of registers and memory locations to determine whether to stop. In your kernel, for example, there might be a way to distinguish the process by its command name or the name of a file it uses, contained in some kernel structures.

Comment: Oh yes, very good idea! I will dig this way. As you say, the process' command name is a good mean to distinguish it from others.  Thanks Mark